# I need to get a nested element in a json array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

There is some list of elements in json format, it looks like this:

```
  [{
          'id': 0,
          "name": "Category name1",
          "services": [{
              "id": 0,
              "name": "Product name1"
          }, {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Product name2"
          }]
      },
      {
          'id': 1,
          'name': "Category name2",
          "services": [{
              "id": 0,
              "name": "Product name1"
          }, {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Product name2"
          }]
      }
  ]
```

I'm trying to get only the entire "services" array from the first category. Conditionally, I'm trying to get it as follows:

```
  this.class = this.http.get('/assets/products.json');
  this.class.forEach(element => {
              if (element.id == ID) //The ID is obtained when calling the function in which this code is executed
              {
                  console.log(element.services);
              }
          }
```

However, this gives me absolutely nothing and "undefined" is output to the console, however, with the same array and under the same conditions on the site https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach it (foreach and console.log) outputs everything I need.

```
//The same foreach only on the mozilla website
array1.forEach(item => {
  if(item.id==1){ //1 вместо ID
    console.log(item.services);
  }});
```

Output to the console: Array [Object { id: 0, name: "Product name1"}, Object { id: 1, name: "Product name2"}]. 
P.S. I don't really need this list of products in the console, I'm trying to pass a variable, but since undefined is passed to the variable, as well as to the console, I can't use the variable and call it to display products on the page. All this is used in the typescript angular project.

Comment: Maybe the "ID" is undefined. Could you please check if the "ID" is passed correctly ?

Comment: Yeah, ID is undefined. But "if" is work and it outputs all classes and products if i send
this.class.forEach(element=>{
if(element.id==ID){
console.log(element) //without .services
}
})
Which says that the ID is being read

Comment: this.rout.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
console.log(this.classID = params.get('class.id'))
}
Returns index if there is a page id in the address bar, in my case it is 1, but passes it to the function described above in the undefined question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpClient` methods like `get` return observables, to which you need to subscribe to in order for the request to even get executed. In your situation, the `class` property is only holding a reference to the observable returned by calling `this.http.get`. Try subscribing to the observable and use the result to extract the data that you need.

```
this.http.get<any[]>('/assets/products.json').subscribe((data) => {
  this.class = data;
  this.class.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.id == ID) {
      console.log(element.services);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think this would work, but the ID is undefined and apparently therefore "if" does not work, however, if you put an integer (for example, 0 or 1), everything outputs as it should.

Comment: My fault: I passed the ID value to ngOnInit, not to constructor. I fixed this mistake and everything works. Thank you and everyone who answered.